# $\int{\frac{1}{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)^2}\;dx}$, where $\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma < 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I'm trying to solve this partial fraction integral 
$$\int{\frac{1}{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)^2}\;dx}$$
where $a\neq 0$ and $\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma< 0$.

This is an irreducible polynomial with a raised power.

So far I have tried to apply it into the form
$$\frac{1}{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)^2}=\frac{Ax+B}{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)^2}$$
$$1=(Ax+B)(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)+(Cx+D)$$
I have tried to proceed with $A,B,C=0$ and $D=1$, but it brought me back to 
$\frac{1}{(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)^2}$.

Also I think I can take the $\alpha$ out as:
$$\frac{Ax+B}{\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+\beta \frac{x}{a}+\frac{\gamma}{a}}$$
but don't know how to proceed with a raised power 2.

Comment: First step is to simplify the integral, by noting that since $\alpha \ne 0$, you can take it out of the integral sign, so WLOG we can consider
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+\beta x + \gamma\right)^2}
$$
instead, where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ have been conveniently rescaled by $\alpha$ and hence satisfy $\beta^2 \le 4\gamma$, making the polynomial irreducible. Now apply partial fractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**.

- Assume $\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma< 0$. Then one may write $$
     \begin{align} \int{\frac{1}{(\alpha x^2+\beta
     x+\gamma)^2}\;dx}&=\frac1{\alpha^2}\int{\frac{1}{\left[\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{4\alpha\gamma-\beta^2}}{2\alpha}\right)^2\right]^2}\;dx}
     \\\\&=\frac1{\alpha^2}\int{\frac{du}{\left[u^2+c^2\right]^2}}, \quad
     \left(u=x+\frac{\beta}{2\alpha},\,c=\frac{\sqrt{4\alpha\gamma-\beta^2}}{2\alpha}\right)
     \\\\&=\frac1{\alpha^2c}\int{\cos^2\theta}\:d\theta, \quad u=c\,\tan \theta.
   \end{align} $$ Hope
  you can finish it.
- The case $\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma= 0$ gives  $$ \int{\frac{1}{(\alpha
     x^2+\beta
     x+\gamma)^2}\;dx}=\frac1{\alpha^2}\int{\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}\right)^4}}
     $$ which is manageable.

Comment: This approach is amazing.

Comment: @Oloa Ah, now I get it. Thank you.

Comment: @tooooony You are very welcome.